# C# Class initialization with different arguments?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have a class, which I initialize with the normal `public Class1(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { ... }`
which is fairly simple.
But what I want to achieve is that the arguments needed change.
For example, If you pass `1` to `arg1`, then the second and third argument dont take an Int but a float instead.

Is that possible to do in C# .NET Core?
If not, is that possible at all in C#?
And how?

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking about is constructor overloading.  You can make as many different constructors as you like on your object.

Comment: That sounds like a weird thing to do - why do you need to make the types dependent on the first parameter? Why not just create different overloads (and skip that first parameter)?

Comment: No, this is not possible. You might want to describe what you're trying to achieve and we can probably help you with alternative approaches.

Comment: @David How do I do that? Like, whats the basic syntax?

Comment: What you're describing requires dependent types which C# does not support. Do you have an example of why you need to do this?

Comment: @JH_WK: The basic syntax for defining a constructor?  A quick Google search finds this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors (among many others).  You should really be starting with an introductory tutorial on C#.

Comment: Define two constructors with different arguments. That's called overloading, simple as that

Comment: For more clarity create factory method with specific arguments and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create two different overloading constructors like that:

```
public Class1(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
     if(arg1 == 1) {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong constructor");
     }
     ...
}

public Class1(int arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {
     if(arg1 != 1) {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong constructor");
     }
     ...
}
```

Or, if you like it a bit easier without exceptions (this would be my preferred way):

```
public Class1(int arg1, float _arg2, float _arg3) {
     if(arg1 != 1) { // Your int constructor, use arg2 and arg3 vars declared below
         int arg2 = (int) _arg2;
         int arg3 = (int) _arg3;
         ...
     } else {
         // Your float constructor, use the _arg2 and _arg3 as your floats
         ...
     }
}
```

Your intended solution to change the variables at runtime is not possible, but I think the last code i posted comes pretty close.

Comment: Well explained, thank you! That did it. But the float-thing was just an example. I am taking strings or ints. But the first option is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload your constructor as

```
public Class1(int arg1, float arg3)
```

Comment: If you do that, the consumer can decide which overload they use, irrespective of `arg1`'s  value.

Answer (score 0):

So I did find another answer.

You can just create one constructor with all the arguments, then allow them to be null, and later check which ones are null and which are set.

Might not be the best way to do it, but it works... Not gonna use it, but just thought of it...